# Pass Jquery alias into javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im creating a theme for wordpress and I need to use some jQuery. Ive found bits of code online and ive made a few bits myself. However, when using jQuery provided by wordpress it is in noConflict mode and instead of using $ it is set to "jQuery". That is fine but I dont want to have to modify all my code and any code I find online to use "jQuery" instead of $.

So it tells me that by placeing `function ($)` at the end you are able to use the $ as the jQuery alias, but only in that functions scope. That is fine, but I was hoping that it would work and pass through to the functions I call from inside that scope. That is where my problem is. How can I make the jQuery code that uses $ inside my "resizeandcenter" function work.

```
jQuery('.artworklist > li > a > img').load(function ($){
   resizeitems('artworklist');
});
```

This is my function that I want to be able to use the $ inside as I dont want to have to modify all my code / and any code I find online.

```
function resizeitems(elementname){
    //Do some jquery stuff using $
}
```

Perhaps there is an alternative way to do what I am doing or I am doing it wrong?

EDIT:

My function "resizeitems" is on its own in a js file thats included in my page header.

The other code, the jQuery code in my first code block is at the bottom of the page in a script block.

So im a bit unsure about the answer saying to wrap my function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass jQuery into the top-level closure containing your code. Usually this is inside the `$(document).ready()` call. A basic example looks like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
      function resizeitems(elementname){
          //Do some jquery stuff using $
      }
      $('.artworklist > li > a > img').load(function (){
          resizeitems('artworklist');
      });
});
```

`jQuery` is now aliased to `$` inside of that closure.

Comment: I dont have a top level closure. The `jQuery('.artworklist > li > a > img').load(function ($){` block is directly after my `<script>` tag. The function resizeandcenter is just in its own js file and is included in the header

Comment: Why not put all the code in one file, and wrap it as I've described?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your entire code in a self executing closure (or an on ready/load closure) like this

```
(function ($) {
    // do your stuff here
}(jQuery));
```

Then you can use $ within that closure

Here is an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7FqXW/) for you

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    (function ($jq) {
        $jq("body").append($jq("<div>").text("hello"));
    }(jQuery));
}, false);
```

Here is an example using jquery's [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event listener

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    (function ($jq) {
        $jq("body").append($jq("<div>").text("hello"));
    }(jQuery));
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/maPAr/)

Or a further alternative in jquery, mostly syntax change, [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16487597/592253) by @[Mathletics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7469/mathletics)

```
jQuery(function($jq) {
      $jq("body").append($jq("<div>").text("hello"));
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ndvrg/)

Comment: This is the correct way to use an immediately invoked functional expression (IIFE)

Comment: Hi, I have seen a few bits like this before but I really cant see or understand how to use it in my case.

Comment: I think you're throwing OP off by switching up the example event binding.

Comment: So I would stick my functions inside 
`(function ($) {
    // do your stuff here
}(jQuery));`
and then I can still call the functions as normal etc?

Comment: @binarysmacker because I do not have enough information to advise the exact solution for your situation, I would suggest using the self executing closure first, if it doesn't work then you will most likely need to wait until the DOM is loaded, by using the ´load´ event or jquery's ´ready´ event binding.

Comment: Im happy to provide more information. I assumed I provided everything in the first place. What else would you need to know?

Comment: From what you have further described then you need to wait for the DOM by using the one of the methods mentioned

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29748/discussion-between-binarysmacker-and-xotic750)

Comment: Did you actually try wrapping your code in the external file that contains ´resizeitems´? And you may have to return any required functions into the global space from your closure.

Answer (score 0):

All what matter is scope here. If your other functions are in some other scope you can just remap global jQuery to $ in that scope, so that you don't have to change the code.

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

You can even set it in global scope, but you may affect other usage of $ on the page if it was used for something else:

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```

Comment: This works! But this means that any kind of function or code I write I need to include this line at the top? I was hoping for some kind of method where I would not have to modify or add and extra code, maybe it doesnt exist?

Comment: The question here would be, why did they make it noConflict? Perhaps $ is already used for something else, and this would just overwrite it breaking the web page.

Comment: It is good practice to use some scope all the time and not to pollute global scope. So if scoped correctly you will need to define this only one time for the whole scope.